# SQL conversation/chat-like output

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a conversation-like output of a MySQL table I which looks like this:

```
Content           From           To           Date
Lorem             36             3            10-10-2014
Ipsum             3              36           10-12-2014
Dolor             36             4            11-10-2014
```

And I want it to output like a conversation, so only the last message between two users will be shown (order by a date). So the user with ID 36 will see this above table like:

```
Content          From            To           Date           
Ipsum            3               36           10-12-2014
Dolor            36              4            11-10-2014
```

So "Lorem" won't be shown because Ipsum is a newer message between the same users.

EDIT:

I now use this Query, but this won't output the latest message if this is send by the user itself:

```
SELECT content, sent
FROM personal_messages pm
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX( id ) id, from_user, to_user
    FROM personal_messages
    WHERE from_user = 46 OR to_user = 46
    GROUP BY to_user, from_user
) pm2 ON pm.id = pm2.id
INNER JOIN users u ON pm.from_user = u.id
ORDER BY pm.sent
```

I hope someone can help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28027459/return-a-conversation-list-and-the-last-message-of-each-message-using-php-and-my/28028206#28028206

Comment: Try this: `select content, send from personal_messages where 46 in (to_user, from_user) order by max(Date) limit 5`. Wrap `Date` around backticks and tweek the `limit` to your like. Or change the `where` to look for dates that are between a threshold (like, for example, in the last 5 days).

Answer (score 0):

know it may be to late to answer, but just in case this helps some1 - the below query does just what is requested by OP - 4 selects and 2 joins.

```
$sql="
SELECT T2.maxDate, T2.user2_id, T2.ava, T2.userName,chat.user_to,chat.user_from,chat.body,chat.viewed FROM 
(SELECT T1.user2_id, users.userName, users.ava, max(cdate) maxDate FROM
            (SELECT chat.user_to user2_id, max(msg_time) cdate
                FROM chat WHERE chat.user_from=18
                GROUP BY chat.user_to
            union distinct
            (SELECT chat.user_from user2_id, max(msg_time) cdate
                FROM chat WHERE chat.user_to=18
                GROUP BY chat.user_from)) T1
            inner join users on (users.userID = T1.user2_id)
            group by T1.user2_id
            order by maxDate desc) T2
            join chat on (T2.maxDate = chat.msg_time) ORDER BY T2.maxDate DESC";
```